# Travelling from UK to Australia with creatine and whey protein

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, food-and-drink

I am travelling to Australia next month from the UK, and would like to take my pack of Whey Protein and tub of Creatine with me.

Am I best to take these in carry on, or checked luggage?

I have a brand new, sealed, 1kg bag of Whey powder, and a tub of already opened Creatine tablets.  Both clearly labelled from MyProtein UK.

Also, will this cause hassle when going through customs, and what should be declared?

Thanks!

Comment: Just generally, to check everything you are importing, that is natural or could be considered a weapon, as well as medicines and other goods, you can use this [site](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in/list-of-items#)

Comment: Also make sure you keep the label, and that the label states the place of production as of this import condition [Bicon](https://bicon.agriculture.gov.au/BiconWeb4.0/ImportConditions/Conditions/CasePathwaySection?EvaluatableElementId=412258&Path=UNDEFINED&UserContext=External&EvaluationStateId=184c8b96-461b-400b-85d5-03de10f187c1&caseElementPk=1175967&HasAlerts=False&HasChangeNotices=False&PathwayPk=4&ConditionElementPK=1071321). If it is manufactured in the UK it is fine.

Comment: If you're transiting through the US, be aware of TSA's rules concerning powders in carry-on: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-policy-powders-are-they-allowed

Answer (score 5):

Remember that Australia is extremely [strict about biosecurity](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in/declare-it), and you could be fined if you don't declare something that should have been declared, even if it is allowed. Because whey is made from milk, it is a dairy product, and you should tick Yes to the appropriate question on the incoming passenger card.

> 6. Meat, poultry, fish, seafood, eggs, dairy, fruit, vegetables?

After you go through the SmartGate and reclaim your baggage, show your whey and creatine at customs/biosecurity and you should have no problems.

Comment: thank you.  Im guessing they will be fine in my checked luggage then

Comment: When you declare it, you will be asked to move to a different queue where an official will check what you are bringing as declared on the card.This happens after you have gathered your check in baggage. This is when I landed in Darwin, probably same in all Australian airports.